# Silverlight 5 Treeview Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework

I'm having issues doing Drag and Drop with a TreeView in SilverLight.  I want to be able to reorder items in a TreeView.  For example, reparent an item.  I am using EntityFramework with a hierarchical relationship (ID, ParentID).  Here is my xaml.

```
<toolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <sdk:TreeView Name="treeView1" Height="176" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto">
      <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocationName}"/>
         </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   </sdk:TreeView>
</toolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget>
```

I created some Event Handlers to see if the drag and drop events were working and they were.  Silverlight also give visual feedback that the drag is happening.

One thing I wonder about is that the Collection that is bound to the TreeView is not an ObservableCollection.  The Children property of the Entity is an EntityCollection.  I'm not sure what I can mess with in the EntityObject.

Anyone have any ideas??

UPDATE:  If I drag a child node to any node in its upper or lower tree, nothing happens.  If I drag a child above or below a root node, a line appears in the tree view.  If I drop it there, I get a null reference exception.  I cannot pin it down.  I know there is a lot going on in this question, but I think we are getting close.  Any help or insight is appreciated.

UPDATE 2: I'll add some screen shots to show what is happening.

[image: This is a sample treeview.]
Sample treeview

[image: TreeViewItem Drag]
This is what it looks like when I drag an item.  I'm trying to drag Milky Way to be a root node with no parent.  Notice the Line at the top.  I assume this is the drop location.  If I drop it there, I get the exception.  Let's say I drag Solar System to be a direct child of Universe.  Nothing happens.  No line appears either.